# form of Sendmail not working with gmail laravel

Tags: laravel, email, gmail

I have a problem in my Laravel project 
when I send email to gmail the form function not work 
 in

```
public function build(request $request){
   return $this->view('email.contactemail',['msg'=>$request->message])->from($request->from, $request->name)->subject($request->subject)->to('email@gmail.com');
}
```

It works but I found my email in gmail message not the email in side the function from(`$request->from`, `$request->name`) why this happened?

Comment: Gmail doesn't allow spoofing of `From` unless you've got that address added to your Gmail as a verified alias. Set a `replyTo()` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: I do not want to show from in the message in Gmail @ceejayoz

Comment: If you set a `from` that's not under your control, it a) will be overwritten by Gmail and b) likely be seen as spam if you send it via another provider.

Comment: okeey thanks @ceejayoz